# Proxy all requests to server in React using createProxyMiddleware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy

So on my dev env, I have a React Server on `localhost:3000` and a NodeJs server on `localhost:5000`.

I have used createProxyMiddleware in React to configure the requests. Here is my config:

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    module.exports = function (app) {
      app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/auth/google', {target: 'http://localhost:5000'}));
      app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/auth/currentUser', {target: 'http://localhost:5000'}));
      app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api/*', {target: 'http://localhost:5000'}));
}
```

All of these routes work without any problems. For example I have a route like `localhost:3000/api/list` which gets routed to `localhost:5000/api/list`.

But now I have a route like `localhost:3000/api/list/3132133ffdvf`. The random string is some id. This above route does not get proxied. It gives me a 404.

Why is this happening? It shouldn't happen since I have created a proxy for `/api/*`. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard (`*`) only matches one directory level. This means that it matches `/api/list` but not `/api/list/id`, since the latter has two levels.

Either remove the wildcard, or use a globstar (`**`):

```
app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api', {target: 'http://localhost:5000'}));
```

or

```
app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api/**', {target: 'http://localhost:5000'}));
```